# Regex to replace characters between strings

Tags: regex

Suppose I have an email address, 'abcdef@gmail.com'. I want to replace all the characters between 'a' and 'f' so the result would look like 'a****f@gmail.com'.

Trying to do this with a regex and replace

```
str.replace(/^(.*?)@/gi, '*');
```

But the results look like this

```
*gmail.com
```

Is there a way to do what I need?

Comment: Try this: ^[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%'*+-\/=?^_`{|}~](.*?).@

Comment: This was a solution that I found that works perfectly in node.js, but uses look aheads and behinds. str.replace(/(?!^).(?=[^@]+@)/gi, '*')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a `replace` with a callback, where the user middle part can be also replaced with `*`s:

```js
var email = "abcdef@gmail.com";
document.write(email.replace(/^(.)(.*)(.@[^@]*)$/, function(m, g1, g2, g3) {
  return g1 +  g2.replace(/./g, "*") + g3;
}));
```

Here is how the "outer" [`/^(.)(.*)(.@[^@]*)$/`](https://regex101.com/r/fR9qJ7/1) regex works:

- `^` - matches start of a string
- `(.)` - Group 1: any first character
- `(.*)` - Group 2: any characters up to the character before the last @`
- `(.@[^@]*)` - Group 3: one character before the last `@`, then `@` and then any 0+ characters other than `@` up to...
- `$` - end of string

The `.replace(/./g, "*")` will just replace any character with `*`. And it will be done only on the Group 2.

The regex you suggested in the comment should also work.

`/(?!^).(?=[^@]+@)/g` matches any character but a newline that is not the first character (`(?!^)`) and that has 1+ characters other than `@` after it and a `@`.

```js
var re = /(?!^).(?=[^@]+@)/g;
document.body.innerHTML = "fake@gmail.com".replace(re, "*");
```

Comment: Interesting approach. I'm going to accept this one because your solution works in both client and server javascript environments. I also found this regex that works in node, but uses look aheads and behinds. str.replace(/(?!^).(?=[^@]+@)/gi, '*')

Comment: `(?!^).(?=[^@]+@)` only uses lookaheads and will work in JavaScript. It matches any character but a newline that is not the first character (`(?!^)`) and that has 1+ characters other than `@` after it and a `@`.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer to your actual question, but I'd like to challenge you that your idea is not a good one.  It's best **not** to show how long an email address is by replacing the internal letters with the same number of `*`s.  It's better to use a fixed number of `*`s.

You seem to be using javascript, which doesn't have lookbehind assertions, and capturing in this case may be simpler to understand too, so I'd do this to replace with a constant number of `*`s

```
str.replace(/^(.).*(.@)/, '$1***$2')
```

Comment: Thanks, this is actually a very good idea and I'm using it. I can't accept the answer you gave for my question though, sorry. =)